# Programmatically change/edit JavaScript function using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function

The website uses `onLoad` to load a `JavaScript` file (`.js`).
I want to change one of the functions inside that js file using JavaScript.

The function is called "`Hello13`" and is among many other functions (`hello5`, `hello6`, etc..)

The `Hello13` function looks something like this:

```
function hello13(x, y, z) {
    if (x == null) {
        //something, something.
    }
    if (y == null) {
        //something else, something else.
    }
    if (z == null) {
        //something diffrent, something diffrent.
    }
}
```

So as you can see, when the function is called it is given some values (`x, y, z`).

I want to "*hard code*" the z to be my own value (inside the js file).

So it would be something like this after i have Programmatically changed it:

```
function hello13(x, y, z) {
    z = MyValueOverride.
.....
```

How can i add my own "`z`" value inside the js file, After the site has loaded, using JavaScript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's a globally defined function in some javascript that is loaded via an inline script tag (either locally defined or in an external JS file), you can just redefine it with your own version of that function.  Whichever definition comes last will be the active one.

So, it sounds like what you want to do is to provide your own definition right after the external JS file containing the target function.  That way your definition will replace the original one.  If you want to retain the original one, you can assign it to another variable name before replacing it.

```
// save original function reference (if desired)
var originHello13 = hello13;

// now define the new function which will replace the previous definition
function hello13(x, y, z) {
    z = MyValueOveride...
}
```

If the external javascript file is dynamically loaded, then things are a little more complicated because you will need to figure out how to know when the dynamically loaded external JS file has been loaded so you can then define your override.  You'd have to show us more about how the external JS file is loaded for us to offer specifics on how to do that.

Comment: The js is loaded like this: `<script type="text/javascript" src="/p/jsFile.js"/>` in the HTML `header`

Comment: @AleksanderAzizi - No problem then.  Just place your new definition after that `<script>` tag.

Answer (score 4):

Redefine it.  If you want to use the logic in the original function, store the reference to the original function and then redefine it and call the original from the new one:

```
var originalHello13 = hello13;
hello13 = function( x, y, z ){
    z = MyValueOverride.
    return originalHello13( x, y, z );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a closure that redefines the function, then call the old function whenever your new function is called:

```
hello13 = (function () {
    // Keep a reference to the old function
    var _hello13 = hello13;

    // return a new function, which will be stored in hello13
    return function (x, y, z) {
        z = MyValueOverride;
        return _hello13(x, y, z);
    };
}());
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hKavH/

Comment: You're not calling the function, and even if you do the `_hello13` var gets instantiated to `undefined` (the value of `hello13` when your code runs)

Comment: @cwolves - How do you figure? I added a fiddle to my answer.

Comment: Your fiddle is different because they're in the same context so the `var hello13` gets hoisted above the function declaration.  In the "real-world" example of them being different scripts, your code is effectively: `var hello13 = undefined`, thus deleting the original function, then `hello13 = (function...`.  Once `var _hello13` runs, the original function is gone.  Drop the `var` before `var hello13` and it should be fine.  It's not needed anyway because you're trying to redeclare the global function

Comment: @cwolves - Isn't [this Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/jvrnFpundPEqgociRBoC?p=preview) indicative of how the OP might use this?

Comment: huh.  That's weird, I didn't think that would work.  I'm a little confused right now.  Maybe because it's in the same scope the `var` is ignored since it's already defined?  If so, I'm not sure all browsers would do the same thing here?  If it's in a different scope, the code definitely won't work, so I wouldn't consider this "safe" in any case.